# Get count attribute from a sql statement in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following sql statement in ruby code-

```
m = Table.find_by_sql(select id,count(*) from table group by id)
m.each do |h|
   puts h.id
   puts h.acount
each
```

I am able to access h.id but I am getting an error while accessing h.count. How can I go about this?

Comment: Use an alias. `select id,count(*) size`

Comment: Yes +1. And this is a very common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving an alias to the count:

```
m = Table.find_by_sql(select id, count(*) AS theCount from table group by id)
m.each do |h|
    puts h.id
    puts h.theCount
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another way to approach this is to use active record rather than `find_by_sql`

```
m = Table.group(:id).count
# Now you have a hash of id => count
m.each do |key, value|
  puts key # id
  puts value #count
end
```